# How to determine if something is 1 row vs 3 rows in bootstrap?

Tags: layout, bootstrap

In the following layout,  how do I determine if each element should be in their own row and column or if all of them should be in 1 row and 1 column together,  but separated by line breaks?  Is there a some sort of rule that can be followed to determine these types of choices?

[image]

Comment: This is a matter of typography not UX

Comment: @icc97 - I just used typography as an example, but it could have been 3 images stacked vertically.  Is that one row/column with 3 images or is it 3 rows with a column in each (each column holding one image)?

Comment: In the example you gave there is a hierarchy - so it makes sense that one is above the other. With images they are typically at the same level in the hierarchy - so they can appear next to each other. But it entirely depends on the images. However still none of this is UX - this has to do with design. You could try asking this on webdesign SE but I'm not sure you'll get much there either. You should have a specific example in mind not just 'something' in X columns or Y rows - otherwise even if it's not off topic it will get rejected for being too broad. Plus bootstrap doesn't impact this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they will ever be side-by-side in any of your views then you will want them to be in the same row in separate columns. If they will never be side by side you can put them in the same row and column. There should always be a row.

And don't use linebreaks, instead this should be controlled in your stylesheet for future updates so designers/devs don't have to edit the markup in individual places. They would rather make one update in the CSS and see the changes reflect everywhere.